# Compare 2 lists and get new list of both of the results without duplicates

Tags: c#

```
            List<string> list1 = new List<string> {"jos", "eva"};
            List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "jos", "eva", "bart"};

            //Result
            List<string> list3 = new List<string> { "jos", "eva", "bart"};
```

i need to compare 2 lists of the same type and i need to get a new list with all the values but no value can be dubble in the new list. i tried already with a a dubble for each but the result is to big.

Comment: already asked ... you don't wana compare but combine or concat or merge without duplicates in C# ... that's enough for google to give an answer

Comment: thank you didn't found that

Answer (score -1):

Import `System.Linq`.

Use `Enumerable.Concat()` to concatenate two or more lists.

On the new merged list instance, use `Distinct()` to get a list of values without duplicates in it.

Read:

- https://www.techiedelight.com/join-two-lists-csharp/
- https://vmsdurano.com/various-ways-to-get-distinct-values-from-a-listt-using-linq/